# Attach document from SharePoint List to GridView

Tags: attachments, gridview

I have a SharePoint 2010 list, which has attachments!!

I am using a custom grid-view to display some selected List fields from the list.

I would like to include the attachment as an embedded document in the Grid-view, Is that possible?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by embedded document? Do you just want to include a link to the attachment in the grid?

Comment: @KitMenke I thought I will show the file in a cell, not the content. On double click of the file would like to open it in word document !! Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're working in server side code:

Take a look a the [Attachments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.attachments.aspx) property of the [SPListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms415089.aspx), it returns an [SPAttachmentCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spattachmentcollection.aspx), from there itterate the [SPFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.aspx)s and use the Url property to get the site relative path and you should be sorted from there.

Some times the docs on MSDN are actually quite helpful :)

Comment: That was great Gavin :) Let me try this :)

Comment: Hi Gavin got this worked!! Created an Itemtemplate with anchor control to Image then set the HREF property of the anchor tab to the retrieved attachment URL ...